# If I have a class of 17 women and 10 men and take a random sample of n=3, what is the probability that on my third draw i select a man?

Tags: probability

> If I have a class of 17 women and 10 men and take a random sample of n=3, what is the probability that on my third draw I select a man?

I thought you put the samples back every thus making the probability 10/17 of picking a man on the 3rd try.  I believe you select one draw, then a second, then an third. I can't find a formula in my book, but i thought it would be 10/17, however, I realize that's an error so I now think it is 10/27.

Comment: You need to add the [self-study] tag (as this sounds very much like a homework problem) and indicate what you've tried. I also think you need to make the details clearer. Are these individuals selected at the same time or do you select one draw, then a second, then a third?

Comment: sorry, first time on here.  it is a homework problem.  i believe you select one draw, then a second, then an third.  i can't find a formula in my book, but i thought it would be 10/17, however, i realize that's an error so i now think it is 10/27.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) as @MattBrems suggested.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $\frac{10}{27}$, same probability as your first and second draw. This might seem strange in a sample without replacement but think of it like that:  imagine that the people are *randomly* ordered in a list and then drawn *in that order*. By randomness the probability that a man occupies the third position is then $\frac{10}{27}$.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you.  Is there a formula for that or is it just as simple as adding the two together?  I ask because I have another probability question that i thought was even harder (using normal approximation of the binomial).

Comment: I'm sorry, add what together? The men and the women you mean?  If so, yes you need the denominator to be $27$. This is a regular counting problem, I doubt there is need for the normal approximation.